# How can I implement own webrtc server in my project?

Tags: webrtc

I want to implement webrtc server in my project. I want to make my own webrtc server and deploy it in amazon server. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I want to make own STUN server also. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adrian Ber is correct, you need a signalling server such as this one:

https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

You can set one of these up on AWS

You'll also need some code on the client side. There is a matching javascript client library (which does most of the work) here: http://peerjs.com/

There are some examples on the peerjs web site - they either need to be run on your local machine or on https servers (browsers will no longer allow camera access over http)

Answer (score 3):

WebRTC is a peer-to-peer protocol so you don't need a server for this.

You will need a signaling server for session negotiation. How you'll implement this depends on the technology that you'll use - client side: polling, ajax, websockets, stomp etc and server side.

For STUN/TURN you can deploy an existing server or use RFC and develop your own from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the people saying that WebRTC is peer to peer only. There is no reason why you can't implement an application, run it on a server, and treat it as a 'peer' for the sake of webRTC when it is actually a server.

That said, we've looked into pulling the WebRTC implementation out of Chrome, but it is a huge task. Depending on what you want to do, you will likely only need to support a subset of WebRTC functionality (Data channel / unreliable for example if you're doing a multiplayer web game).

There might be a few implementations out there that have cropped up now, but last I checked there wasn't anything of note.